# How to make better movement for game objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I'm making pong with HTML canvas and JavaScript, and I am having trouble with the movement of the ball. If you position the paddles in a way that they hit the ball, and then you just leave them there, the ball will just continue in an infinite loop bouncing between the paddles, and the top and bottom of the screen. How can I implement a random number to make the ball move in the opposite direction but slightly differently? If you need any more code than this, let me know. Thx

```js
// Ball to paddles collision detection

function ballToPaddlesCollisionDetection(a,b) {
    if(a.X < b.X + b.width && a.X + a.width > b.X && a.Y < b.Y + b.height && a.Y + a.height > b.Y) {
        ballDX = -ballDX;
        ballDY = - ballDY;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to multiply that value by a random number between 0.9 and 1.1 for example... to change the direction a little bit

Comment: @Pipe Thx but could you give an example of what you mean? I tried to implement that idea, but it isn't working at all lol.

Comment: `ballDX = -ballDX * (1+(Math.random()*0.1)-0.05)`... same applies with ballDY, its really hard to know the exact value... I don't know in which range ballDX or ballDY are.

Comment: for example if ballDX is 5  , you are not converting to -5, probably to -4.9 or -4.97, or 5.05 or 5.09... giving it a tiny desviation.